# Loading a byte from a DB 1, but printf integer show a large number

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, call, nasm

I'm trying to call printf to print an integer, put it doesn't print the right value:

```
section .data

         an:    db 1
         format: db "num: %d" , 10, 0

section .text
         global main
         extern printf

main:
         push ebp
         mov ebp,esp

         mov eax, [an]
         push eax
         push dword format
         call printf

         add esp, 8
         mov esp,ebp
         pop ebp

         mov eax, 0
         ret
```

this code prints "num: 1836412417"

put when I try to print a char it works!

```
section .data

         an:    db 'a'
         format: db "num: %c" , 10, 0

section .text
         global main
         extern printf

main:
         push ebp
         mov ebp,esp

         mov eax, [an]
         push eax
         push dword format
         call printf

         add esp, 8
         mov esp,ebp
         pop ebp

         mov eax, 0
         ret
```

now it prints "num: a"

so what's wrong with the first code ?!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`db` declares 8-bit (one byte) values, while `%d` prints 32-bit (four byte) values on x86.

In effect, when loading 32-bit register `eax` with `mov eax, [an]` you are loading bits of letters `"num"` to high bytes of the register. They are later printed as number, when using `%d` or ignored when using `%c`.

To declare 32 bit values you should use `dd`, instead of `db`.

Answer (score 6):

@zch pointed out the issue. But if you really do want to print out a byte data item as an integer and don't have the luxury of redefining it, you can do it this way:

```
     movsx eax, BYTE [an]       ; [an] is a byte value to be printed with %d
     push  eax
     push  dword format
     call  printf
```

The `movsx` instruction sign extends an 8-bit or 16-bit operand (in this case, the 8-bit operand, `[an]`) into the 32-bit register, `eax`. If it is unsigned, then you'd use `movzx eax, [an]` (zero fill).
Normally in C, the promotion to integer is done implicitly. But in assembly, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: @3la210 I've included this alternative answer so the options are understood.